# Kubernetes Architecture / Design /?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, architecture

I’m trying to figure out and learn the patterns and best practices on moving a bunch of Docker containers I have for an application into Kubernetes. Things like, pod design, services, deployments, etc. For example, I could create a Pod with the single web and application containers in them, but that’d not be a good design.

Searching for things like architecture and design with Kubernetes just seems to yield topics on the product’s architecture or how to implement a Kubernetes cluster, and not the overlay of designing the pods, services, etc.

What does the community generally refer to this application later design in the Kubernetes world, and can anyone refer me to a 101 on this topic please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes is a complex system, and learning step by step is the best way to gain expertise.  What I recommend you is [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/) about Kubernetes, from where you can learn about each of components.

Another good option is to review [70 best K8S tutorials](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/70+Best+Kubernetes+Tutorials), which are categorized in many ways.

Designing and running applications with scalability, portability, and robustness in mind can be challenging. Here are great resources about it:

- [Architecting applications for Kubernetes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/architecting-applications-for-kubernetes)
- [Using Kubernetes in production, lessons learned](https://techbeacon.com/devops/one-year-using-kubernetes-production-lessons-learned)
- [Kubernetes Design Principles from Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuIQurh_kDk)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no *Kubernetes* approach but rather a *Cloud Native* one: I would suggest you [Designing Distributed Systems: patterns and paradigms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491983647) by Brendan Burns.

It's really good because it provides several scenarios along with pattern approached and related code.

Most of the examples are obviously based on Kubernetes but I think that the implementation is not so important, since you have to understand why and when to use an *Ambassador* pattern or a *FaaS* according to the application needs.

Comment: Thank you all. This is all very useful information. Agree it’s a complex topic. Lots of reading and learning here for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this can be quite complex and that's why it is important that software/platform architects understand K8s well.

Mostly you will find an answer on that which tells you "put each application component in a single pod". And basically that's correct as the main reason for K8s is high availability, fault tolerance of the infrastructure and things like this. This leads us to, if you put every single component to a single pod and make it with a replica higher than 2 its will reach a batter availability.

But you also need to know why you want to go to K8s. At the moment it is a trending topic. But if you don't want to Ops a cluster and actually don't need HA or so, why you don't run on stuff like AWS ECS, Digital Ocean droplets and co?

Best answers you will currently find are all around how to design and cut microservices as each microservice could be represented in a pod. Also, a good starting point is from RedHat [Principles of container-based Application Design](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.redhat.com/cms/managed-files/cl-cloud-native-container-design-whitepaper-f8808kc-201710-v3-en.pdf)
or [InfoQ](https://www.infoq.com/articles/kubernetes-effect/).

Answer (score 0):

Un kubernetes cluster is composed of:

1. A master server called control plane
2. Nodes: nodes which execute the applications / Containers or pods

By design, a production kubernetes cluster must have at least a master server and 2 nodes according to the kubernetes documentation.

Here is a summary of the components of a kubernetes cluster:

Master = control plane:

- kube-api-server: expose the kubernetes api
- etcd:  key values store ​​for the cluster
- kube-scheduler: distributed the pods on the nodes
- kube-controller-manager: controller of nodes, pods, cluster components.

Nodes = Servers that run applications

- Kubelet: runs on each node, It makes sure that the containers are running in a pod.
- kube-proxy: Allows the pods to communicate in the cluster and outside
- Runtine container: allows to run the containers / pods

Complementary modules = addons

- DNS: DNS server that serves DNS records for Kubernetes services.
- Webui: Graphical dashboard for the cluster
- Container Resource Monitoring: Records metrics on containers in a central DB, provides UI to browse them
- Cluster-level Logging: Records container logs in a central log with a search / browse interface.